# How to get date as finename in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to save get request data in csv format using python, the objective is to save the data in csv in a defined folder with filename as "abc_soi_today's date-1". for example

case 1: if i run the code today i.e. 15th july 2021 then the file name should be "abc_soi_20210714"

getting error in my code[image].

```
import urllib.request as req
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def download_csv(download_url):
    request = req.urlopen(download_url)
    yesterday = datetime.date().today().isoformat().replace("-", "") - timedelta(1)
    filename = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    file = open("C:\\Users\\atul.sanwal\\Desktop\\" + filename + '.csv', 'wb')
    file.write(request.read())
    file.close()


download_csv("http://uspvalpc064:8080/python-toolkit/natwest/file?source=dataDelivery&type=soi&destination=pv&asof=20210714")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

yesterday = datetime.today().date() - timedelta(days=1)
filename = yesterday.strftime('%Y%m%d')

print(filename)
```

Output:

```
20210716
```

Comment: how can i subtract 1 business day from current day and use that date as filename? let say if current day is monday and i need to subtract 1 buisness day then it should reflect Friday date in filename

Comment: @Naina, that is a separate question. Stackoverflow does not promote adding questions and answers in comments. If this answer fulfills your current question, mark it as accepted. We may continue answering in a different question. Thanks.

Comment: i found the answer to my second question : yesterday = datetime.today().date() - BDay(1)